# storing the argument of a function in a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store a value of an argument of a function to a variable.

```
var store;

function load_event(page_id){
    store = page_id;
    alert(page_id); //Works fine
}

alert(store); //Undefined???
```

The page_id is the argument got from another PHP file (so that PHP file is calling the function).

I do not understand why this store variable returns undefined?

PHP CODE!

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php 

                $post = $wp_query -> post;
                $post_id = $post->ID;
                echo $post_id; //Get the post_id of the current post.
            ?>
            <script>    
                loadEvent("<?php echo json_encode($post_id); ?>");
            </script>



    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: `load_event` is being called after line `alert(store);`. So the time the alert executed the `store` value hasn't been updated, this could be `async` issue.

Comment: In the code above, you haven't called the function, therefore the variable `store` is still undefined.

Comment: @some Because OP told that line `alert(page_id);` works fine, so It has been called somewhere, the problem is it's being called after the line `alert(store);`.

Comment: @Mritunjay I'm very well aware of that. If you reread what I wrote you see that we mean the same thing: that the variable is undefined sine it has not been set at the time `alert(store)` is executed.

Comment: how can I make it defined then?

Comment: You must wait to use the value until load_event has been called. The easiest way is to put all your code that is dependent on that in a function, and call that function from load_event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `load_event()` before `alert(store)`. The reason is that you are using `alert(store)` before the function `load_event()` has been called. At this point, the value in `store` is undefined. That is because the `load_event()` function is not executed until you call it so `alert(store)` is executed first and which evaluates `store` to `undefined` and then `load_event()` is executed that sets the value of `store` to `page_id`. Move the  `load_event()` before `alert(store)` will solve the problem.

Comment: @wordwannabe Yes, you put that after where you DEFINED the function, but you are still calling `alert(store)` before the load_event has been CALLED.

Comment: Yes... that works but just wanna know the way to put it inside JS

Comment: some do you know why putting the function inside jQuery(document).ready function makes the function undefined when it is called in PHP?

Comment: Could you give us some more code? Are you including that javascript file that has load_event function at the bottom of html page or at the top? If it is at the top then move it down to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function to execute the function

```
var store;

function load_event(page_id){
    store = page_id;
    alert(page_id); //Works fine
}
load_event(2);

alert(store); //2
```

Comment: yes if you see the PHP code I called the function so that is why alert(page_id) is working but I have created js file that defines the function and the variable and then stored there.

Comment: you need the second alert after executing the function call.
try putting second alert in the php after calling the function.

Comment: that works... :P but I really wanna know the way to include alert inside JS file...

Comment: try to put second alert inside document.ready. In this case that alert will be called alter document ready (after executing the function)

Comment: @wordwannabe: “yes if you see the PHP code I called the function” — sure, but if the line `alert(store);` runs *before* you call the function (in the line `loadEvent("<?php echo json_encode($post_id); ?>");`), then `store` will be undefined when `alert(store);` runs, because `loadEvent` hasn’t been *called* yet. (Other people have already said this, I’m just saying it in a different way to try to help you understand it.)